How to resize figure to fit window on event in matplotlib?
I've already got help with this problem, but stuck again.
I'm trying to pre-generate and store matplotlib figures in python, and then display them on a keyboard event (left-right cursor keys).
It is working fine, but will not fit the figures (after the first one) to the window.
How can I do that?
If I manually resize the window, then the figure will be adjusted to fit, but it is not working automatically.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def new_figure(title, data):
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8), dpi=80) 
    plt.plot(data, label=title) 
    ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('value')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title(title)
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig

def show_figure(fig):
    dummy = plt.figure() 
    new_manager = dummy.canvas.manager 
    new_manager.canvas.figure = fig 
    fig.set_canvas(new_manager.canvas) 

def redraw(event, cnt):
    event.canvas.figure = figs[cnt]
    event.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
    event.canvas.draw()

def keypress(event):
    global cnt
    if event.key == 'right':
        cnt += 1
        cnt %= mx
    elif event.key == 'left':
        cnt -= 1
        if cnt < 0:
            cnt = mx-1
    redraw(event, cnt)

d = range(0, 360)
data = []
data.append(np.sin(np.radians(d)))
data.append(np.cos(np.radians(d)))
data.append(np.tan(np.radians(d)))
titles = ['sin','cos','tan']
mx = len(data)

figs = []
for i in range(mx):
    fig = new_figure(titles[i], data[i])
    figs.append(fig)

cnt = 0

show_figure(figs[0])
figs[0].canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
plt.show()


I suggest to link your previous questions in the body of the new one.
